# Having trouble creating a template variable($templatevars) for an array PHP

Tags: php

Im having trouble loading an array into the templatevars variable 
It seems to be unidentified everytime i run it 
and it doesnt seem to be putting the array into the variable 
I would appreciate any help i can get with this Thanks

Here is the code I'm using

```
<?php
require '../template.php';
$title = 'List';

if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $jokes = find($pdo, 'jokes');
        $applications = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) as count FROM applications WHERE jokeId = :jokeId');

        $applications->execute(['jokeId' => $jokes['id']]);
        $applicantNumber = $applications->fetch();
        $categoryList = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = :id');

        $values = [
            'id' => $jokes['categoryid']
        ];
        $categoryList->execute($values);
        $categoryName = $categoryList->fetch();

        $filterCity = find($pdo, 'jokes');

        $templateVars = array(
            'jokes' => $jokes,
            'category' => $categoryList,
            'applications' => $applications,
            'jokes' => $filterCity,
            'categoryList' => $categoryName,
            'applications' => $applicantNumber
        );
    } else {
        $jokes = find($pdo, 'jokes');
        $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/jobListing.html.php', $templateVars);
    }
} else {
    $output = loadTemplate('../Templates/login.html.php', []);
}
require '../Templates/layout.html.php';
```

Comment: In your first else you call $templateVars, it is not defined as you do that in the if statement and not in the else part

Comment: so would the fix be to copy the $templatevars variable and array into the else statement?  Because i have tried that and it didnt work either

Comment: The array is called $templateVars